# App crash when saving a realm object... RLMAccessor set object to nil

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am getting a crash whenever I save a realm object, the crash point to a property of type SaleItemVariation which sets nil from `RLMAccessor.mm`.

```
if (_promote_existing && [obj isKindOfClass:_info.rlmObjectSchema.objectClass] && !prop.swiftIvar) {
        // set the ivars for object and array properties to nil as otherwise the
        // accessors retain objects that are no longer accessible via the properties
        // this is mainly an issue when the object graph being added has cycles,
        // as it's not obvious that the user has to set the *ivars* to nil to
        // avoid leaking memory
        if (prop.type == RLMPropertyTypeObject) {
            ((void(*)(id, SEL, id))objc_msgSend)(obj, prop.setterSel, nil);
        }
    }
```

My classes:

```
final class SaleItem: Object, Mappable{
    .....
    @objc dynamic var variation: SaleItemVariation! 
    ......

    var singleQuantityPrice: Double {
        return variation.price // Crash here, Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value 
    }   
}

class SaleItemVariation: Object, Mappable{
          @objc dynamic var price: Double = 0
  }
```

I don't have any idea why is this happening?

Note: Realm version is `2.10.2`

Comment: did you find any solution, i am having the exact same . @MohamMad Salah

Comment: @dip I guess you have to check your object's properties have not been set to nil by others, maybe two classes having the same property type and reference it inside Realm table and one of them removed (cascade) and remove that record with it

Comment: i am not deleting or nilling value as my app is used for data display purpose only.

Answer (score 1):

saving an realm object must be inside the realm block.

```
try? realm.write {
  //realm add
  //realm update
  //realm delete
}
```